# Android: Waiting for the threads to finish executing the method

Tags: java, android, multithreading, download, wait

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
List<Future<Object>> results = new ArrayList<Future<Object>>();

// submit tasks
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    results.add(exec.submit(new ThreadTask()));
}

...

// stop the pool from accepting new tasks
exec.shutdown();

// wait for results
for(Future<Object> result: results) {
    Object obj = result.get();
}


class ThreadTask implements Callable<Object> {

    public Object call() {
        // execute download
        ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't show me the results I expected. In more detail, I'm doing a download manager for android. These threads are for downloading the file in segments. Since, each segment may take different time duration to download, I think that's where the problem lies.

Then I tried using just a simple number return inside the method. Then the threads started to give the expected results.

So as a solution I thought of implementing a method to wait for all the threads to finish executing. In the above code, How do I wait for all the threads to finish their work?. I think I have to use the `wait()` method but I have no idea how to do it.Hope you can help to figure out this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `The above code doesn't show me the results I expected.` What are the expected results and what are you seeing?

Comment: What is not working about the code? Does it not terminate?

Comment: The loop with `result.get()` should wait for the threads to terminate. Is it not working?

Comment: @Tudor: it doesnt terminate, doesnt return me a single value either. But when I just change the code to return a simple int value assigned by me to return, it will successfully return. I think its because inside the download() method each method might take different time durations to download, caz its using HTTPConnections to connect and download.

Comment: @user1122359: Then it seems to me that your `call` methods are not returning. Can you post the actual code?

Comment: @Tudor: So I thought the best solution would be to wait for all the threads to finish their assigned work and then try taking their return values.

Comment: @user1122359 You're already waiting for all the threads to finish; that's what the `shutdown` call does. If it doesn't terminate, then at least one thread isn't terminating; that's what you need to fix. We can't tell you why because you haven't shown us that code.

Comment: Try adding a log before the return result; to check which threads return.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a set of threads to meet at some point - try to use the "Barrier" pattern.

Java SE has it's implementation : java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier

From docs : A synchronization aid that allows a set of threads to all wait for each other to reach a common barrier point. CyclicBarriers are useful in programs involving a fixed sized party of threads that must occasionally wait for each other. The barrier is called cyclic because it can be re-used after the waiting threads are released.

A CyclicBarrier supports an optional Runnable command that is run once per barrier point, after the last thread in the party arrives, but before any threads are released. This barrier action is useful for updating shared-state before any of the parties continue.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html